# Trying to flip an array around but keep getting an error

Tags: java, arrays, compiler-errors

Attempting to test and see if an array is a palindrome, however, the `flipArray` method I created keeps giving me trouble. The compiler gives a "not a statement" error and I'm not sure what is stopping it. The code is supposed to flip array `b` around, then compare array `a` and array `b` to see if they are the same:

```
public class Lab13_2{
    public static final int SIZE = 50;
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Boolean palindrome = false;
        String[] a = {"hello" , "goodbye", "goodbye" , "hello"};
        String[] b = new String[SIZE];


        b = a.clone();     
        palindrome = getPalindrome(a,b,a.length);
    }

    public static boolean getPalindrome(String[] a, String[] b, int arrayLength{
        b = flipArray(b);
        for(int i = 0; i <arrayLength; i++){
            if(a[i] != b[i]){
                return false;
            }
        }
        return true;
    }

    public static String[] flipArray(String[] array){
        for(int=0; i <array.length/2; i++){
            int temp = array[i];
            array[i] = array[array.length-1-i];
            array[array.length-1-i] = temp;
        }
        return array;    
        }
    }
```

Comment: @Ousmane Mahy Diaw you're joking with the edit rejection right?

Comment: @axlj your edit was reasonable, However, it did not take into consideration the spelling mistakes of OP which I have amended.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you're missing the closing `)` for the `getPalindrome` method.
2. your for loop within the `flipArray` method doesn't declare `i` before it's used within the condition or elsewhere. should be `for(int i = 0; i < array.length/2; i++)`.
3. your `temp` variable should be of type `String` rather than `int`.

Lastly but not least you don't compare strings like this:

```
if(a[i] != b[i])
```

change it to this:

```
if(!a[i].equals(b[i]))
```